# Out of the two which would be considered better code (less chance of bugs) for counting the number of lines in a text file?

Tags: c

I want to count the number of lines in a text file, I was able to do that using two different ways. I was wondering which is a better option and why or are they both the same and why?

Code Snippet #1:

```
{
 FILE *infile;
 int count=0;
 char filearray[1024];

 infile=fopen(filename,"r");

 if(infile==NULL)
   {
    perror("Could not open file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while(fgets(filearray, BUFSIZ, infile) != NULL) 
   {
      count++;
   }

}
```

Code Snipppet #2

```
{
  FILE *infile;
  int c,count=0;

  infile=fopen(filename,"r");

  if(infile==NULL)
   {
     perror("Could not open file");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   for (c = getc(infile); c != EOF; c = getc(infile))
    {
     if(c=='\n')
     count++;
   }

 }
```

Comment: The first would produce wrong results if the line is longer than `BUFSIZ`

Comment: What happens when `i > 1023` and you write outside the bounds of your array?

Comment: And yep, why do you even need a `filearray` in the #2?

Comment: So you want us to do your homework?

Comment: @zerkms Where would I store the characters read if I do not have a file array?

Comment: @abginfo No, this is not homework. I am only curious.

Comment: @AMD you have the current character in `c`, why do you need to keep all the characters?

Comment: @zerkms Thank You for pointing it out. I did not realize that.

Comment: @AMD the thing that should have made you concerned is that `filearray` is not used anywhere (in #2).

Comment: You'll have to define "better". Faster? Less memory? Less chance of bugs?

Comment: @Schwern Less chance of bugs

Comment: AMD, Should the last "line" in a file not end with a `'\n'`, there is not wide agreement if this counts as a line. In C, "Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is  implementation-defined."  C11 §7.21.2 2.  For your purpose, you can defined that case any way you want, but since it is a not-so-uncommon case, best to document your choice.

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering which is a better option and why or are they both the same and why?

They are not the same.

The first approach (`fgets()`) reports 1 if the file was `"abc"`.  The second  approach (`getc()`) reports 0.

If the file is one long line (2000 characters `"xxx..xxx\n"), the first reports 2, the second reports 1.

---

Instead consider a 3rd approach that counts the number of times the beginning of a line was seen which reports 1 for both cases mentioned above.

```
int c;
int previous = '\n';
for ((c = getc(infile)) != EOF) {
  if (previous == '\n') count++;
  previous = c;
}
```

In terms of "better", the first consideration is getting the correct functionality, then address performance.  I'd choose [door #3](https://blog.codinghorror.com/monty-hall-monty-fall-monty-crawl/)

---

BTW, the line count can exceed `INT_MAX`.  Go for a wide type

```
unsigned long long count = 0;
...
```

Comment: What is address performance?

Comment: @AMD The phrase *"then address performance"* is short for *"then think about how to improve the performance of the code"*. As Schwern found out, the `fgets` solution is much faster than the `fgetc` solution. So solution #4, which uses `fgets`, but correctly handles line truncation, is the best solution (it's correct *and* fast).

Comment: @chux After reading your answer I looked at how `wc` does it as it's both correct and fast. [Read a buffer, count the newlines, repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49889360/14660).

Comment: @chux: If a file is one long line why does fgets reports as 2 and getc as 1?

Comment: @AMD 1st, `char filearray[1024]; ... fgets(filearray, BUFSIZ, infile)` is poorly coded.  It should be `fgets(filearray, sizeof filearray, infile)`.  That reads up to 1023 characters and counts that as a line.  It then reads (2000-1023 per this answer's long line example) on the second iteration. 
 Net result: `count++;` called twice.  `getc()` only sees 1 `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

For the least chance of bugs, use `wc -l`. :) That's what I used to make sure I got this right. (Don't actually shell out to `wc -l` in a C program, shelling out to utilities is fraught with peril).

Otherwise, ***if used properly*** they're both quite simple pieces of C code. `fgets` is maybe a bit simpler and `while( (c = getc(fp)) != EOF )` is quite easy to get wrong, but they're both very familiar C idioms.

But `fgets` is clearly much faster.

```
int count_fgets( FILE *fp ) {
    int count = 0;
    char buf[1024];

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

int count_getc( FILE *fp ) {
    int count = 0;
    int c;

    while( (c = getc(fp)) != EOF ) {
        if( c == '\n' ) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Running this over the [Gutenburg text edition of War and Peace](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2600/2600-0.txt) (which is technically UTF-8, and this is only for ASCII, but it doesn't matter for our purposes) I get...

- `wc -l`: ~15ms
- `count_getc`: ~190ms
- `count_fgets`: ~15ms

I'm a bit surprised there's such a large difference and I'm not sure why.

---

***UPDATE***

After seeing [@chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49889774/14660) and edge cases, I decided to see [how `wc` does it](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c#L298). It goes something like this.

```
int count_wc( FILE *fp ) {
    char buf[BUF_SIZ];
    size_t bytes_read;
    int count = 0;

    while( (bytes_read = fread( buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), fp )) > 0 ) {
        char *p = buf;
        char *end = p + bytes_read;
        while (p != end) {
            if( *p++ == '\n' ) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Read a chunk, look for newlines, repeat. Pretty simple once you see it. But it *still* only counts newlines. If you want to catch that last line, you can remember the last character in each buffer and look at it outside the loop. This will be the last character in the stream.

```
int count_wc( FILE *fp ) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    size_t bytes_read;
    int count = 0;

    char last = '\n';

    // Count all the newlines.
    while( (bytes_read = fread( buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), fp )) > 0 ) {
        char *p = buf;
        char *end = p + bytes_read;

        while (p != end) {
            if( *p++ == '\n' ) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        last = *(end-1);
    }

    // If the last character in the file isn't a newline,
    // count that last line.
    if( last != '\n' ) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

This is the fastest, usually about 11ms, and I believe most correct.

Comment: Did you get the same answer from both?

Comment: @user3386109 Yes. Good question. :)

Comment: @Schwern What unit is ms?

Comment: @AMD: "ms" is milliseconds.

Comment: Try [getc_unlocked](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc_unlocked.3p.html). You can easily fix the `fgets` solution by only counting a line read if its last character is really a newline (or it's the last line in the file). That will slow it down a bit, though.

Comment: @rici `getc_unlocked` is indeed significantly faster, ~25ms, but that's a lot of caveats that I wouldn't feel safe using it. As for `fgets`, I thought about that. It that would require scanning each line for a newline twice; once inside `fgets` and again to look for the last character. Instead I looked at how `wc` does it. Similar idea, but instead of using `fgets` just use `fread` and count the newlines in each buffer. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Schwern Parsing the buffer from `fgets()` is a problem should _null characters_ get read.  Sticking with `fread()` is easier.

Comment: @chux A good point! And I *finally* solved the no-final-newline problem efficiently. Geez, even `wc -l` doesn't handle this.

Comment: @chux Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @schwern: `getc_unlocked` is perfectly safe in unthreaded code. It's also safe if only one thread is using that `FILE*`. Or, finally, you could use `flockfile`.  But one or both of the first two conditions is almost certainly true in the context of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The first code example is a simple line reader, but it assumes that lines will always contain less than 1024 characters. If lines larger than 1024 characters exist, then they will be counted as multiple lines.

The second code example has a dangerous bug. If the file contains more than 1024 characters, it will try to store the line data in unallocated memory. This will produce undefined behavior of your program (crashing, unexpected results, etc).

If you really only need to count lines and nothing else, the second code is better, but you should remove the array. You don't need to remember the line information, thus discard those unneeded characters immediately.